How to sync main and thumbnail carousel in splide carousel with Nuxt 3?
I'm trying to implement a thumbnail carousel using splidejs in Nuxt 3.
//Main carousel
<div id="main-carousel">
    <Splide :tag="ul" :options="mainOptions" aria-label="Images">
        <SplideSlide v-for="(img, index) inimages">
            <NuxtImg :src="`/images/${img[0]}.png`" :alt="img[1]" />
        </SplideSlide>
    </Splide>
</div>

// Thumbnail carousel
<div id="thumbnail-carousel">
    <Splide :tag="ul" :options="thumbsOptions" aria-label="Images">
        <SplideSlide v-for="(img, index) inimages">
            <NuxtImg :src="`/images/${img[0]}.png`" :alt="img[1]" />
        </SplideSlide>
    </Splide>
</div>

and in script setup
const mainOptions = {
    type: 'loop',
    perPage: 1,
    perMove: 1,
    pagination: false,
};

const thumbsOptions = {
    type: 'slide',
    rewind: true,
    gap: '1rem',
    pagination: false,
    fixedWidth: 110,
    fixedHeight: 70,
    cover: true,
    focus: 'center',
    isNavigation: true,
    updateOnMove: true,
};

I'd like to sync them both but it is not working.
I'm using Nuxt3 and nuxt-splide module.

Given the snippets, should work well. What exactly is the problem here? Also, do you mind sharing a small [repro]?
